# RetroFit Call fails after first time

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview, nullpointerexception, retrofit2

My RetroFit call that gets a list of two strings and two objects succeed on the first time but the response every time after that gets an empty body for some reason.
This is the Adapter for it:

```
public class AssistsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AssistsAdapter.AssistsViewHolder> {
private List<TopAssists> mTopAssistsList;
private int mRowLayout;
private Context mContext;
public class AssistsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    LinearLayout assistsLayout;
    TextView playerRank, playerAssists, playerName, playerTeam;

    public AssistsViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        assistsLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.assists_layout);
        playerRank = itemView.findViewById(R.id.assists_rank);
        playerAssists = itemView.findViewById(R.id.assists_assists);
        playerName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.assists_player);
        playerTeam = itemView.findViewById(R.id.assists_team);
    }
}

public AssistsAdapter(List<TopAssists> topAssistsList, int rowLayout, Context context){
    mTopAssistsList = topAssistsList;
    mRowLayout = rowLayout;
    mContext = context;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public AssistsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(mRowLayout, parent, false);
    AssistsViewHolder holder = new AssistsViewHolder(view);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(AssistsViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.playerRank.setText(String.valueOf(mTopAssistsList.get(position).getRank()));
    holder.playerAssists.setText(String.valueOf(mTopAssistsList.get(position).getAssists()));
    holder.playerName.setText(mTopAssistsList.get(position).getPlayer().getName());
    holder.playerTeam.setText(mTopAssistsList.get(position).getTeam().getName());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return this.mTopAssistsList.size();
}
```

This is the fragment that initiate the RetroFit call:

```
public class TournamentsInfoFragment extends Fragment {
private final static String TAG = "Call Failed";
private StandingsAdapter mStandingsAdapter;
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
private String mTournamentId;
private String mRegion;
private String mKey;
private GoalsAdapter mGoalsAdapter;
private AssistsAdapter mAssistsAdapter;
private TextView mFailedMessage;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_standings, container, false);
    // Initializing the failure message in case of an error
    mFailedMessage = view.findViewById(R.id.standings_failed);
    // Getting the arguments from the previous fragment
    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    mTournamentId = bundle.getString("tournament_id");
    mRegion = bundle.getString("region");
    mKey = bundle.getString("key");
    // Showing the Progressbar
    mProgressBar = view.findViewById(R.id.standings_progress_bar);
    // Creating an instance of the ApiInterface
    ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
    // Calling to get the standings from the API
    Call<StandingsResponse> call = apiService.getStandings(mRegion, mTournamentId, mKey);
    // Logging the URL Call
    Log.wtf("URL Called", call.request().url() + "");
    call.enqueue(new Callback<StandingsResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<StandingsResponse> call, Response<StandingsResponse> response) {
            // Checking the response code to act accordingly
            if(response.code() == 404){
                mFailedMessage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            else{
                if (response.body() == null){
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                           R.string.standings_problem, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                else {
                    generateStandings(response.body().getStandings());
                    mStandingsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<StandingsResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e(TAG, t.toString());
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.enqueue_failure, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
    // Calling to get the Goals and assists leaders from the API
    Call<LeadersResponse> leadersCall = apiService.getLeaders(mRegion,mTournamentId,mKey);
    // Logging the URL Call
    Log.wtf("Leaders URL Called", leadersCall.request().url() + "");
    leadersCall.enqueue(new Callback<LeadersResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<LeadersResponse> call, Response<LeadersResponse> response) {
            // Checking the response code and acting accordingly
            if(response.code() == 404){
                mFailedMessage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            else{
                if (response.body() == null){
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                            R.string.leaders_problem, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                else {
                    generateGoals(response.body().getTopGoalsList());
                    generateAssists(response.body().getTopAssists());
                    mGoalsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    mAssistsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<LeadersResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e(TAG, t.toString());
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.enqueue_failure, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
    return view;
}

/**
 * Method to generate List of standings using RecyclerView with custom adapter
 */
private void generateStandings(final List<Standings> empDataList) {
    mRecyclerView = getView().findViewById(R.id.standings_rv);
    mStandingsAdapter = new StandingsAdapter(empDataList, R.layout.item_standings, getActivity());
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mStandingsAdapter);
}

/**
 * Method to generate List of Goal leaders using RecyclerView with Custom adapter
 */
private void generateGoals(List<TopGoals> topGoals) {
    mRecyclerView = getView().findViewById(R.id.goals_rv);
    mGoalsAdapter = new GoalsAdapter(topGoals, R.layout.item_goals, getActivity());
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mGoalsAdapter);
}

/**
 * Method to generate List of assists leaders using RecyclerView with Custom adapter
 */
private void generateAssists(List<TopAssists> topAssists) {
    mRecyclerView = getView().findViewById(R.id.assists_rv);
    mAssistsAdapter = new AssistsAdapter(topAssists, R.layout.item_assists, getActivity());
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAssistsAdapter);
}
```

It shows the RecyclerView for the first time but every time after that the response body is empty and causes a NullPointerException, I had to create an if statement and Toast just to prevent the application from crashing.
Error Log:

```
6-03 21:55:51.241 6034-6034/com.mad.footstats E/URL Called: https://api.sportradar.us/soccer-t3/eu/en/tournaments/sr:tournament:17/standings.json?api_key=w7c74newrykj8m57rda6xwrk 06-03 21:55:51.253 6034-6034/com.mad.footstats E/Leaders URL Called: https://api.sportradar.us/soccer-t3/eu/en/tournaments/sr:tournament:17/leaders.json?api_key=w7c74newrykj8m57rda6xwrk 06-03 21:55:51.278 6034-6034/com.mad.footstats E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout 06-03 21:55:51.279 6034-6034/com.mad.footstats I/chatty: uid=10085(com.mad.footstats) identical 1 line 06-03 21:55:51.279 6034-6034/com.mad.footstats E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout 06-03 21:55:51.507 1393-3495/? W/audio_hw_generic: Not supplying enough data to HAL, expected position 10934976 , only wrote 10934640 06-03 21:55:51.557 1393-3495/? W/audio_hw_generic: Hardware backing HAL too slow, could only write 0 of 720 frames
```

Comment: Can you provide stack trace. Your exception?

Comment: @Yupi I've added it to the question above.

Comment: You said you get `NullPointerException` and you didn't provide it in stack trace.

Comment: I have said that I was getting a NullPointerException but I contained it by encapsulating it with a Toast, My question is why the response is empty after the first time, not why NullPointerException is happening, it is happening because of the empty body.

Comment: why do you call the network operataion methods in the onCreate()? because onCreate() calls just once and after that does not get called. You need to call on onStart() for example

Comment: @matio Because when this fragment is created the call needs to happen, and when I go back to the previous fragment and then reopen this one the call happens but the body is empty.